# What "Reverse Ring" specs (size..etc) for my Canon 600d for Macro Photography?

Tags: canon, macro, macro-converter

I have these three lenses, and I wonder which one of them is the best to be used with "reverse ring" for Macro Photography?

Camera: Canon EoS 600d

Lenses: 18-55mm, 50mm, 50-250mm

Answer (score 4):

If you want the highest magnification possible, then the 18-55 might yield that at 18mm. But if you want better image quality, the 50mm f/1.8, being a prime will probably yield that.

BTW, there are two *types* of macro reversal rings: ones that let you mount a reversed lens directly to the camera mount, and others that are basically male-to-male filter rings, which let you mount one lens reversed on the face of another lens mounted on the camera.

See also: http://digital-photography-school.com/reverse-lens-macro-close-up-photography-lesson-3/

Answer (score 0):

One might wish to inquire “what’s the advantage of reversing a lens”. The normal design of a camera lens is to image a curved vista and project this image on a flat surface such as film or digital chip. When we image super close, in most cases the subject will be flat or nearly flat and depth-of-field will be super shallow. Best we use a lens that is optimized to image flat surfaces. By reversing the lens we are using the back-focus to image and the front-focus to project on the sensor. The back focus is optimized for a flat subject. Additionally, the reversing ring adds space; the lens barrel is placed further away from the chip’s surface. This added distance yields a little more magnification. A macro lens is optimized to image at “unity”. This is life-size (1:1).

Comment: Have you considered just asking the question "How does lens reversal work for macro?" and then answering it? As it stands, this doesn't actually answer the OP's question of "what lens do I use with a reversal ring?"